# How can I develop a widget which can set update frequency and enable/disable auto update?

Tags: android, widget

I want to develop a widget which can set update frequency and enable/disable auto update?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf can be of some use.